# Removing Closing vote after question has been edited

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, editing, vote-to-close

Is there a way to remove a closing vote if a question has been edited? If not, would it be useful to have that possibility?

I just edited [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/where-to-find-people-interested-in-collaborative-work-between-designers-and-prog), that I had previously voted to close, and I think it now fits the site better (it has more votes too). It's a shame I can't withdraw my vote. What do you think?

Comment: Based on your comments here (and on the edit), I "flushed" close votes on that question by closing and reopening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, unfortunately. It has frequently been requested at MSO, and denied. Sorry.

Comment: The canonical `[feature-request]`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: @Aarthi What's the deal these days with close-votes expiring? Poking around on meta.SO it sounds like close votes used to disappear after 2 days, then it was changed to disappear after 4 days and only if a question has had 100+ views (that's quite a lot of views for a small-ish site, e.g. Yisela's example question has 82 at time of writing this). I can't see how to find out if that's still the case.

Comment: @user568458 What you've said sounds to be correct -- I'll see if I can dig up the documentation/meta post.